cannot find bash sub-file when include externalt configs in gitlab ci
I have code in gitlab ci yml file:
include:
  - project: 'my-group/my-project'
    ref: main
    file: '.gitlab-ci-template.yml'

but the file .gitlab-ci-template.yml uses come code from another utils-functions.sh file (located in the same directory)
during the run of pipeline it can not find  utils-functions.sh 
how could I fix it ?

I presume you mean that "utils-functions.sh" is located in the my-group/my-project repository.
In which case what you are trying to do cannot work: GitLab does not merge the repositories when merging pipelines, it merges just the GitLab CI yaml files specifically.
You need to create a job in the ci template file that writes the bash script out to disk:
write-it:
  script:
  - |
    cat > utils.sh << EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "hello world"
    EOF

